# Cannot set the build action to GoogleServicesJson using FirebasePushNotificationPlugin [Xamarin][Android]

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification

I am trying to implement push notification using [FirebasePushNotification](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/README.md). As suggested, I first added the Nuget package to my project and then the google-services.json file generated from FCM to my android project, but I am not able to set the build action of the file to GoogleServicesJson. Anyone facing the same issue?

I am using Visual Studio for Mac version 8.7.8. Please let me know if I am missing anything.
Thank you in advance.

update: i have tried re-starting the solution, delete json file, clean and rebuild and add again. nothing works! :(

Comment: restart visual studio and then try to set build action

Comment: @zubairz Tried. Didnot work for me.

Comment: Try Delete file and add again and clean rebuild

Comment: tried that also. :(